# Unity avoid hardcoding values?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, object, variables

In a click handler, I'm saving a reference to a ScriptableObject like so:

```
actionSO=itemScriptableObject.actions.action1;
```

I have several different actions attached to this gameObject:

```
itemScriptableObject.actions.action1;
itemScriptableObject.actions.action2;
itemScriptableObject.actions.action3;
```

Upon clicking, I need to figure out which action to select and act out based upon a global variable.

```
actionPicker=action1;
```

The action names (action1, action2, action3) correspond to the variable name. So, when the variable actionPicker value changes - it should hook up directly to the corresponding scriptableobject action. In JS it would look something like:

```
itemScriptableObject.actions[actionPicker];
```

But I have no idea how to write this in C#?

I have it working using a simple hard-coded switch and also placed the values in a separate class to reference, but want to leave the flexibility in place by using a variable reference as shown above.

Comment: Use a dictionary or another collection

Comment: If I use a dictionary or another collection, wouldn't it still need to be hardcoded there?